# TSA Precheck on all connecting flights

Tags: airport-security, tsa, british-airways, alaska-airlines, sea

If my fist leg of international travel is on Alaska Airlines and I have a TSA Precheck, will my connecting flight on British Airways also be TSA precheck?

We start in Sacramento, CA on Alaska Airlines, then connect in Seattle to London on British Airways.

Comment: If you're changing from Alaska Airlines onto BA, you normally wouldn't need to re-clear security as most US domestic flights disembark into the departures area

Comment: @Gagravarr It's true that US domestic flights normally deplane into the departures area, but some airports (e.g. SFO and LAX) have international flights in a different terminal, so you end up having to go through security again anyway. Fortunately for the OP, Sea-Tac is not such an airport.

Answer (score 8):

Any gate at Sea-Tac is reachable from any other gate without passing through TSA security again.

You can walk between concourses A, B, C, and D, but if you are traveling to or from the N or S gates, (you should be as they serve international flights) which are in separate buildings, then you can't walk; you must take the train. You will see signs directing you to trains which you can take between concourses. When you arrive in Sea-Tac, look for signs directing you to the N & S Gates.

[image: Sea-Tac N & S Gates sign]

If you see a TSA security checkpoint from either side, you took a wrong turn. (Though you may see US Immigration on your way out.)

Comment: This is true in a lot of US airports.

Comment: This is a good answer! One reason I love Sea-Tac is that all gates are connected. I have made connections even from C to N in well under 15 minutes.